# How to add text in QR code Image using Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I am using SimpleSoftwareIO (https://www.simplesoftware.io/simple-qrcode/) to generate QR Code in Laravel but I need to add text under QR code and when we download, it should download with text.

By using the below code I am able to create QR code:

In controller

```
$data="Hello";
$path = "logo.png";
$png = QrCode::format('png')->merge($path, .17, true)->size(300)->errorCorrection('H')->generate($data);
$png = base64_encode($png);
```

In blade file

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,{{ $png }}'>
```

[looking for something like this and it should be image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLZow.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your text could be another Image. In Intervention Package you can merge two images vertically to achieve this after the QR code generates.
see: http://image.intervention.io/api/insert

or you can use PHP default function `imagecopymerge`
see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

example:(from official docs)

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$dest = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```